# Spark Dataframe - Get all lists of pairs (Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following situation:
I have a dataframe with an 'array' as the schema. Now I want to get for each array, all lists of pairs and save it again in a dataframe. So for example:

This is the original dataframe:

```
+---------------+
|  candidateList|
+---------------+
|         [1, 2]|
|      [2, 3, 4]|
|      [1, 3, 5]|
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]|
+---------------+
```

And that is how it have to look like after the computation:

```
+---------------+
|  candidates   |
+---------------+
|         [1, 2]|
|         [2, 3]|
|         [2, 4]|
|         [3, 4]|
|         [1, 3]|
|         [1, 5]|
|         [3, 5]|
|and so on...   |
+---------------+
```

I really don't know how this is possible in spark, maybe someone has a tip for me.

Kind regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to create a UDF (User Defined Function) and use it with `explode` function. The UDF itself is simple thanks to Scala collection's `combinations` method:

```
import scala.collection.mutable
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import spark.implicits._

val pairsUdf = udf((arr: mutable.Seq[Int]) => arr.combinations(2).toArray)
val result = df.select(explode(pairsUdf($"candidateList")) as "candidates")

result.show(numRows = 8)
// +----------+
// |candidates|
// +----------+
// |    [1, 2]|
// |    [2, 3]|
// |    [2, 4]|
// |    [3, 4]|
// |    [1, 3]|
// |    [1, 5]|
// |    [3, 5]|
// |    [1, 2]|
// +----------+
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you very much!!

Comment: why do you use `mutable.Seq`?

Comment: Spark's internal representation of array-type column uses a `mutable.WrappedArray`, which extends `mutable.Seq` and not `immutable.Seq` - so using `Seq` here would result in a `ClassCastException`. You can also use `mutable.WrappedArray[Int]`, of course, but that would be more specific than it should.

Comment: I always just use `Seq` without exceptions

Comment: @RaphaelRoth that's interesting, I definitely get an exception. Are you sure there's no `import scala.collection.mutable.Seq` in your scope? And which Spark version are you using? I'm using 2.3.0.

Comment: no I don't import `Seq` because its already available in the default-namespace. I'm  using Spark 2.3.1

Comment: see https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_koCamgLKz3MvdbNXhD437qqhl77MpU8/view?usp=sharing